# Azure Error HTTP 500 en App ¿Sintaxis de php o Servidor?

Tags: azure

tengo archivos para insertar datos en mi aplicación de azure el problema es que solo un archivo de todos los que tengo no inserta la información y me manda a error 500.

mi codigo php:

```
    <?php
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){
  require 'conexion.php';
  crearConfirmado();
}
function crearConfirmado(){
global $connect;

$folio = $_POST["folio"];
$fecha = $_POST["fecha"];
$empaque = $_POST["empaque"];
$acopiador = $_POST["acopiador"];
$factura = $_POST["factura"];
$comision = $_POST["comision"];
$nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
$tipocorte = $_POST["tipocorte"]
$reunion = $_POST["reunion"];
$base = $_POST["base"];
$bandeado = $_POST["bandeado"];
$precompra = $_POST["precompra"];
$ajuste = $_POST["ajuste"];
$preventa = $_POST["preventa"];
$prefinal = $_POST["prefinal"];

$query = "INSERT INTO cortes_confirmados (folio,fecha_hora,empaque,acopiador,factura,nombre,comision,tipocorte,reunion,prebase,bandeado,precompra,ajuste,preventa,prefinal) VALUES ('$folio','$fecha','$empaque','$acopiador','$factura','$nombre','$comision','$tipocorte','$reunion','$base','$bandeado','$precompra','$ajuste','$preventa','$prefinal');";
$query = "UPDATE cortes SET estado='1', posponer='Sin posponer' WHERE folio='".$folio."'";
mysqli_close($connect);
}
?>
```

supongo que es un problema de sintaxis porque sin codigo y solo un `echo"x"` me lo muestra perfecto, no encuentro el fallo.

Comment: ¿ No había otra forma de comprobarlo, mas que preguntar aquí para que otros miren por tí ? ¿ ni logs del *server*, ni herramientas CLI, ni nada ? -1

Answer (score 3):

Te falta un *punto y coma* ( **;** ) :

```
$tipocorte = $_POST["tipocorte"]; // Aquí
```

Comment: punto y coma querrás decir

Comment: disculpa si punto y coma :)

Comment: te amp gracias ♡ jaja